# How do I count number of unique in a row * a counter for Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For this image there are only 2 genres, Fiction and Non-Fiction throughout the entire dataset, I would like to count the total number of Reviews for each Genre.

[image]

So for the first entry, Fiction has 87841 Reviews, and it has to add the 79446 from second entry and so on, until the end.

At the end, there will be Non-Fiction and Fiction, with their respective total number of reviews.

In the end I would like to create a pie chart showing the distribution of them, but how do I get both values in the first place?

Comment: Use a Pivot Table and/or a pivot chart

Comment: If the Pivot Table doesn't suit you, try using a SUMIFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `Name` is in column `A` and you have 100 rows in total (obviously change to match your table).

Therefore as the comments above have stated you can use the `SUMIF` [Excel function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function#:%7E:text=The%20Excel%20SUMIF%20function%20returns,(*%2C%3F)%20for%20partial%20matching.&text=If%20sum_range%20is%20omitted%2C%20the,range%20are%20added%20together%20instead.):

```
=SUMIF(column_to_check, criteria, column_to_sum)

=SUMIF(G2:G100, "Fiction", D2:D100)
```

The assumption above is that the columns that's states 'Fiction or Non-Fiction' is in column G and the number of reviews is on column D.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pivot Chart :

[image]